# Give PHP access to coffee-script node module in OSX

Tags: php, macos, node.js, coffeescript

I've installed coffee-script module globally (with -g key). I can use it from terminal. But php can't do it with **exec** command. There is no output in exec command and no compiling.

In Windows i moved node_modules folder to Program Files instead /LocalRoaming, and then PHP can use coffee command. How to do it in **OSX**?
Coffee bin path is: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

exec() only returns the last line of the output - this may be blank. Pass the second and third params to it as references and var_dump their contents after running exec(). The third param will at least yield the exit code of the programme.

Failing that - give shell_exec() a try.

Comment: I made test case, and use that command: "coffee -bo ./ -c ./$coffee". It works, when I use php from shell, but not work, when it executes apache. It work from _www user, not from me.

Comment: Use the full path to coffee in your command - PHP won't have a $PATH. You're also using "./" presumably to specify the current directory. You'd do well to change directory to be sure you're in the right place. cd /path/to/where/it/should/run/ ; /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee -bo ./ -c ./$coffee